# Generate list of names or words and output them in groups

Tags: java, php, arrays, arraylist

I am looking to take a list of words or names and output them into groups in a specific order via php or Java but have no idea how to do so. I will give an example with the order: (To clarify, this isn't homework. I am doing this for a tournament that I am hosting, and it would make it easy to generate seeds during the event)

Amount of names: 12
Size of Groups: 3

- Hilde Frankum
- Earlie Uphoff
- Rich Laclair
- Vicenta Baskin
- Herminia Lakin
- Hermelinda Hostetter
- Bernice Sylva
- Blossom Nesby
- Lashon Kwan
- Esther Farraj
- Tana Olguin
- Pamula Davin

Output:

Group 1:
Hilde Frankum
Herminia Lakin
Lashon Kwan

Group 2:
Earlie Uphoff
Hermelinda Hostetter
Esther Farraj

Group 3:
Rich Laclair
Bernice Sylva
Tana Olguin

Group 4:
Vicenta Baskin
Blossom Nesby
Pamula Davin

The list takes the name next in line and inserts it into a new group in the order that it is listed in until there are no more groups left and then restarts until there isn't any names left.

Comment: array_chunk to amount/size then take all 1st then all 2nd...

Comment: Not homework. I'm actually running a tournament and this would help with seeding purposes during the actual event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PFB sample code. I have created a Group class which holds an group(array of String objects). An ArrayList which holds random number of Group objects.

Program is dynamic based on input names and Size of Groups:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Group {
    String group[];

    public Group(int groupSize) {
        this.group = new String[groupSize];
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {

        StringBuilder strBuilder = new StringBuilder();

        for (int i = 0; i < group.length; i++) {

            if (i != 0)
                strBuilder.append(", ");

            strBuilder.append(group[i]);
        }
        return strBuilder.toString();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] inputArray = { "Hilde Frankum", "Earlie Uphoff",
                "Rich Laclair", "Vicenta Baskin", "Herminia Lakin",
                "Hermelinda Hostetter", "Bernice Sylva", "Blossom Nesby",
                "Lashon Kwan", "Esther Farraj", "Tana Olguin", "Pamula Davin" };

        int numGroups = 4;

        createGroup(inputArray, numGroups);
    }

    public static void createGroup(String inputArray[], int numGroups) {

        int groupSize = inputArray.length / numGroups;

        List<Group> lists = new ArrayList<Group>();

        for (int i = 0; i < numGroups; i++)
            lists.add(new Group(groupSize));

        for (int i = 0, x = 0; i < groupSize; i++)
            for (int j = 0; j < numGroups; j++)
                lists.get(j).group[i] = inputArray[x++];

        for (Group groups : lists)
            System.out.println(groups.toString());
    }
}
```

Comment: This worked like a charm! I am very thankful :). Now I got to see if I can get it working in php too haha.

Answer (score 0):

```
$arrayOfNames = array(
'Hilde Frankum',
'Earlie Uphoff',
'Rich Laclair',
'Vicenta Baskin',
'Herminia Lakin',
'Hermelinda Hostetter',
'Bernice Sylva',
'Blossom Nesby',
'Lashon Kwan',
'Esther Farraj',
'Tana Olguin',
'Pamula Davin'
);

sort($arrayOfNames);

$ar = array_chunk($arrayOfNames, 3);

foreach($ar as $key => $groups){
    echo "Group #" . ($key + 1) .' '. implode(' ',$groups) . "\n";
}
```

Comment: This wasn't working sadly :/. It either only gave an output of the same letters in the same order or just gave an error. Optimally I would want this to work for php mainly, so I will keep a lookout for more answers from you :). I am also looking at the code myself too

Comment: The first implementation works. Second I have not tested. Example was provided just to show what to do with your collection. My bad if I misled you. If need be and you end up using php just do this

sort($arrayOfNames)
$ar = array_chunk($arrayOfNames, 3);

Comment: Interesting. It doesn't seem to be working for me. The first one seems to be giving me a const error.

Comment: Sorry, I wouldn't know what's the problem (need details if it's a code issue or just doesn't fit your problem), but with php if you want to separate one list into multidimensional list you'd use array_chunk(), it's the easiest way. Then output it whatever you see fit. Let me send you a fiddle

Comment: Thanks! It makes a bit more sense now. The only issue right now is that it's not putting it into the right order. I am not trying to sort it alphabetically, but rather, have it so that each person listed is into that group in that order like the list above.

Comment: in that case just comment sort function. array_chunk is just grouping given array, whatever sorting, not sorting you want to do, you can do before array_chunk() and it should be good

Answer (score 0):

Here's a Java method that should do it.

```
String[][] groupThem(ArrayList<String> /*could be an array without many changes*/ things, int sizeOfGroups){
    int qtyOfThings = things.size();
    int qtyOfGroups = qtyOfThings / sizeOfGroups;
    String[][] groups = new String[qtyOfGroups][sizeOfGroups];

    int counter = 0;
    while(counter < qtyOfThings){
        groups[counter%qtyOfGroups][counter%sizeOfGroups] = things.get(counter);
        counter++;
    }
    return groups;
}
```